# Change any weekend dates that appear in a specific cell to the Friday beforehand

Tags: excel, vba, date

Here is what I have so far. The date is privided on sheet1 but needs to be converted to a weekday on sheet5 if it's not already a weekday. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Sub Weekend_remover()    
    '  determines if date is a weekend and changes it to the friday beforehand.
    If (Weekday(Sheet1!B3, vbMonday) <= 5) Then
        Sheet5!D13 = Sheet1!B3
    ElseIf (Weekday(Sheet5!D12, vbMonday) = 6) Then
        Sheet5!D13 = (Sheet1!B3 - 1)
    Else
        If (Weekday(Sheet5!D12, vbMonday) = 7) Then
            Sheet5!D13 = (Sheet1!B3 - 2)
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: And what isn't working with your code?

Comment: The code cannot work because there is a `End If` missing. Or because the last `Else … If` is meant to be a `ElseIf` instead. Note that spaces and line breaks are very important in VBA.

Comment: Also `Weekday(Sheet1!B3, vbMonday)` is no valid syntax and should be `Weekday(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3"), vbMonday)`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You can do this in Excel with normal formulas easily:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(A1;2)>5;A1-WEEKDAY(A1;2)+5;A1)`

[image]

In case you need an VBA solution, make an UDF and then a macro that loops trough all cells. The UDF would be:

```
Function LAST_FRIDAY(ByVal vThisDate As Range) As Date
Dim ThisDate As Date
ThisDate = CDate(vThisDate.Value)

If Weekday(ThisDate, vbMonday) > 5 Then
    LAST_FRIDAY = CDate(ThisDate + 5 - Weekday(ThisDate, vbMonday))
Else
    LAST_FRIDAY = ThisDate
End If

End Function
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you all so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would use .Range("") to refer to ranges; have a test that you are working with a valid date to start with; use variables and work always with cell containing source date and target cell to put date. Finally, I would use Select Case as my preference

```
Public Sub Weekend_remover()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet, dateCell As Range, targetCell As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set dateCell = ws1.Range("B3")
    Set targetCell = ws5.Range("D13")

    If IsDate(dateCell.Value) Then
        Select Case Weekday(dateCell.Value, vbMonday)
        Case Is <= 5
            targetCell = dateCell
        Case 6
            targetCell = dateCell - 1
        Case 7
            targetCell = dateCell - 2
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub Weekend_remover()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D12")
    v = r1.Value
    dy = Weekday(v, vbMonday)

'  determines if date is a weekend and changes it to the friday beforehand.

    If dy <= 5 Then
            r2.Value = v
        ElseIf dy = 6 Then
            r2.Value = v - 1
        ElseIf dy = 7 Then
            r2.Value = v - 2
    End If

End Sub
```